# Bootstrap 4 makes outline not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

How does Bootstrap disable the HTML outline property? 
When I add the form control class to my input, "outline: none;" no longer works.

```
<input class="form-control" style="outline:none;">
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/Eli92/pen/WXXbRa

I can just use my own css class for this input, but I want to know what's happening here, and I'm too much of a beginner to submit a bug report.

The reason I want to remove the outline is to add my own to an outer element, like Youtube and most popular sites do for their search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, a border and box-shadow are applied to every form-control when focused, so setting

```
.form-control:focus {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

should remove the styling

Comment: Thanks! This is correct, the bootstrap box-shadow looks a lot like the default outline. What got me confused is I went through the styling in the chrome console and deselected each style and nothing changed. Turns out I needed to deselect box-shadow and webkit-box-shadow simultaneously.

Comment: No problem, just so you know, the Chrome console also has a filter at the top with a button saying `:hov` that allows you to view the styling when hovered/active/focused

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you want to know.

Just hopefully I can answer right.

The `outline` of the element is the border around it when you click into it. In your codepen you set the `outline: none` so nothing happens when you click into it. So your `outline: none` works totally fine.

The `border` is the the thing you see right there. Bootstrap also sets a border around it so if you set `border:none` you will get your effect as far as I understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is that bootstrap defines `.form-control`, and that some extra attributes are assigned by this class to bootstrap inputs.

```
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

What you'd want to add to your class to change the border is an override so that there is something else that replaces the default. If you truly want no border on an element, then you'd want to set the border to `0px` thick

```
border: 0px;
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeeNZB

Answer (score 0):

`.form-control` applies a `box-shadow` (not an outline) on `:focus`.  Removing it is as simple as overriding the `.form-control:focus` declaration in Bootstrap:

```
.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```